# 3D projection with camera rotation formula for scratch

Tags: 3d, mit-scratch

I am making a 3D engine for scratch and I got the 2.5D formula so I need camera rotation to make it 3D.The problem is I have no idea of how to make that.

Answer (score 1):

On Scratch, 2.5D and 3D often function very differently. How your project works will depend on what you're trying to accomplish, but the Scratch Wiki does have some tutorials:
https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/How_to_Make_a_Three-Dimensional_Project
https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Raycaster
Griffpatch also created a tutorial if you want something more in-depth, you can watch the first episode at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1c5TcdITVs.